# unable to implement list operations using thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Thread newbie here. In the following code, I want to add elements to the global list using one thread and search for random elements using another thread.

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

list<int> some_list;
mutex some_mutex;

void add_to_list(int new_value)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(some_mutex);
    some_list.push_back(new_value);
}


bool list_contains(int value_to_find)
{
    lock_guard<mutex> guard(some_mutex);
    return find(begin(some_list), end(some_list), value_to_find) != end(some_list);
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        // Add i to some_list through one thread only
        thread t(add_to_list, i);
        t.detach();
        // Search elements in different thread
        thread t2(list_contains, i);
        t2.detach();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I pass i along with add_to_list then that many no of threads are created. I want to add the elements to the list using single thread only. How to do this? Do, I need to pass vector of elements to the thread instead of variable?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `detach()`. In the code above the program starts 200 threads and ends (when `main()` returns) without waiting for any of them to finish. Use `join()` instead, this will allow you to wait for the thread completion properly.

Then, if you want `add_to_list` to be done sequentially, then do that in a separate loop.

For example:

```
int main() {
  vector<thread> threads;
  // Add i to some_list through one thread only
  threads.emplace_back([] {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
      add_to_list(i);
    }
  });
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    // Search elements in different threads
    threads.emplace_back([i] {
      list_contains(i);
    });
  }
  // Join all threads (waits for their completion)
  for (auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
  }
}
```